# Find if table has a specific string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table:

```
Name   Length Description  x
Name1  444    Blabd        x.png
Name2  55     Blabla       x.png
Name3  11     Blaaa        x.png
```

`table id="firsttable"` `img class="delete"`

I have a value (from other table):

```
var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
```

I want to find that value in first column of a table and delete x.png of a row, which has that value.

Something like: (with mistakes)

```
$('#firsttable tr td:first:contents("'+value+'")').closest('tr').find('td:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- use the `:first-child` selector and not `:first`.
- you should use `:contains` and not `:contents` (i don't think there is even a :contents() selector - or maybe via a plugin) (see note)
- `.siblings()` will find the siblings of the current element which is the first TD. You can pass a selector to limit the selection so pass `:last` to get oly the last one. Makes more sense than going back to the parent and find the last TD.
- you can empty the last TD content instead of removing the td element (but you can remove it if you want)

Here's the code:

```
$('#firsttable td:first-child:contains("' + value + '")')
    .siblings(':last')
    .text('');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zRD34/)**

**Note:**

`:contains` will search in text nodes id the specified value is contained, not the exact value! So if you do `:contains("1")` but you have a TD with value "14", it will find it also. If this is a problem you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('#firsttable td:first-child').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === value;
    })
    .siblings(':last')
    .text('');
```

**More info on:**

- [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)
- [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
- [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)